# Rails loading incorrect database config for test env?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Have a weird issue... my tests keep running against my development database. I tried `binding.pry` in `test_helper.rb` here:

```
# this is the top of the file
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
binding.pry
```

And noticed 3 things:

1. `ENV['RAILS_ENV']`/`Rails.env` was set correctly to `"test"`.
2. Rails configuration seems to load the correct value:

   ```
   Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]

   # => {"adapter"=>"postgis",
   #     "encoding"=>"unicode",
   #     "pool"=>5,
   #     "username"=>"user",
   #     "host"=>"localhost",
   #     "database"=>"db_test"} <= CORRECT
   ```
3. ... but ActiveRecord loads an incorrect value:

   ```
   ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]

   # => {"adapter"=>"postgis",
   #     "encoding"=>"unicode",
   #     "pool"=>5,
   #     "username"=>"user",
   #     "host"=>"localhost",
   #     "port"=>5432,
   #     "database"=>"db_development"} <= INCORRECT
   ```

Additionally, `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]` returns a `port` key whereas `Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]` does not.

---

Why are these different? Here's my config:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: user
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db_test
```

I `grep`ed my entire project folder and `config/database.yml` is the only place I name my databases, so there's not another config overriding this one as far as I know.

I'm running `rails 4.2.5`.

Help!

Comment: Do you have `DATABASE_URL` set in your environment?

Comment: @AhmadSherif Ugh, yes. Removing it fixes my issue. Want to post that as an answer and I'll award you the bounty? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `DATABASE_URL` from your environment variables.

Comment: I think I may be having the same issue - where do I check if "DATABASE_URL" is set in my environment?

Comment: @nc14 There are multiple ways; try locating the PID of your Rails app then run `cat /proc/<pid>/environ | strings | grep DATABASE_URL`, or try putting `puts ENV['DATABASE_URL']` inside somewhere in your Rails codebase and check the output (could be in the logs or in the shell you're running it from).